# Mocha testing and three.js; THREE is not defined

Tags: javascript, three.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to run a simple Mocha unit-test for code that uses THREE.js's Vector3 class:

```
import {Vector3} from 'three';
const a = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

When this is run through Mocha (actually mocha-webpack to be precise, where webpack is set to target 'node', rather than 'web'), I get

```
RUNTIME EXCEPTION  Exception occurred while loading your tests
ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
```

As you can see, I'm not referencing the name THREE in my test-code. Turns out THREE is a (global?) object defined in three.js's source code. However, for some reason it now isn't available. How can I get the above test-code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because in webpack configuration "three" was listed in "externals". Removing all externals from webpack's test-configuration solved the problem.

Comment: Don't forget you can accept your own answer. Then other visitors can see that the problem is solved.